# how to center a particular div inside div?

Tags: html, css

How to center a particular div inside div? I have attached an image in here and everything is centered but the label(email,password,forgot password) should start from the textbox

[image]

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="form">
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="email">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try wtih `.container .p{
text-align:center;
}`

Comment: Why are you using `p` tags as labels? use a `<label for="form-field-id"></label>` (and add the unique id to the input) so the field focusses when you click the label. then `.container label { text-align:center; }` to center the label text. I would advise you to use another class, so not every container changes with this style.

Comment: it's not clear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Hello, you should use form element for a form .... what kind of display do you use to layout your form. Text-align on its own do not reproduce your screenshot. Please cllarify your question if you really need an efficient answer.

Comment: Wrap p and input together in an element, center the wrapper element and don't center inner elements

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `text-align: center` will align all your child at the center.

You can use flex-box to achieve your desired output like this.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="form">
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="email">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you could **flexbox**

```css
#container {
  background-color: lime;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  /* Only for demo : */
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.label {
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label for="email" class="label">Email</label>
  <input name="email" type="text">
  <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
  <input name="password" type="password">
</div>
```

As shown in snippet, you can set the base alignement of the container to center, and then specify for each child that you want a specific alignement with the `align-self` property

Doc : [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)
[Self align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self)

Comment: Why still a div tag instead of a real label? A user expects the form field to be focussed when clicking a form label.